# ADO database - how to edit

Tags: c++, database, ms-access, c++builder

I want my server application to have the possibility to edit the database that i have created, when a client wants me(server) to edit something of his. Database table is quite simple, i need to know how to change it programmatically.

For an example:

My database table

-

ID   user   pass   ip

1    test1  pass1  0.0.0.0

2    test2  pass2  0.0.0.0

3    test3  pass3  0.0.0.0

-

How can i change test2 ip address?

BTW using Embarcadero C++ Builder XE3
And the database was created using Microsoft Access

Answer (score 0):

Just drop a TADODataSet component and a TADOConnection to connect to the database.  With the TADODataSet you can use the CommandText to run SQL commands.  That will allow you to manipulate the table in any way you need.  Then it would just be a matter of creating the proper calls for you application to do what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering but, i am a complete beginner so i don't really understand what your saying.

Can you maybe do an example of changing a column 3 and row 2, to something else?

And how can i find a person and retrieve his location from the dtb?

Comment: The TADOConnection will get you connected to your Access database.  The TADODataSet would have the SQL to make the change you want to make, which you could run on a button click or something.  The SQL to change the row is basic look here for that:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp.  You would just plug in the value from an editbox or something like that from your form.